# Change table column into jquery calendar on button click in datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have the following datatable:

[image]

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
 <table id="rentals" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead  bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
        <tr>                   

            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Date Rented</th>
            <th>Estimated Return Date</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>              
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
table = $("#rentals").DataTable({
    ajax: {
              url: query,
              dataSrc: ""
          },

          columns: [
                    {
                        {
                        data: "book.title"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "dateRented",
                        render: function (data) {
                            returnDate = data;
                    },
                     {
                        data: "estimatedReturnDate",
                        render: function (data) {
                                var date = new Date(data);
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                var day = date.getDay();
                            return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                     }
          ]
});
```

I want the "Estimated Return Date" column to change into jquery datepicker with default value equals to the date value of that column when the user clicks on "Click me" button and changes back to text field when a user clicks on let's say a cancel button.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple event listener should do the job. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
  var td = $(this).closest('tr').find('.date');
  var picker = td.find('.datepicker');
  if(picker.length){
     td.html(picker.val());
  }else{
      td.html('<input class="datepicker" value='+td.text()+'>');
      var picker = td.find('.datepicker');
      picker.datepicker();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<table id="rentals" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead  bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
        <tr>                   
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Date Rented</th>
            <th>Estimated Return Date</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Book</td>
                <td>20/12/2017</td>
                <td class='date'>20/12/2017</td>
                <td><button>Click me</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I has to twick it little to make it work with datatable. If I wanted to eliminate the "Click me" button and do the toggle of datepicker on the column itself.. how can I access the td ?

Comment: just add some class to this column and use this class in event handler `$(document).on('click','.some-class',function(){..`.